# Get the current value FROM Cassandra - Update USING TIMESTAMP?

Tags: transactions, cassandra, timestamp, insert-update

I create a simple table with timestamp
how to insert on it the timestampvalue also i want to use the current valueoftimestamp to do UPDATE later !

I used this instruction:

```
UPDATE users SET   timestampid =  dateof(now())  WHERE id= userID  ;
```

got this value on my table:

```
2016-04-14 11:18:12+0200
```

now want to do UPDATE USING This value

```
 UPDATE users USING TIMESTAMP '2016-04-14 11:18:12+0200' SET   timestampid =  dateof(now())  WHERE id= userID  ;
```

> Invalid null value of timestamp ?

How to get the current timestampValue from Cassandra when using:

```
Update USING TIMESTAMP valueoftimestamp
```

to check if there's Modification or not using timestamp.

Comment: The question is not making any sense in current form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise and moved the main question in the body. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide more details that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

you should specify TIMESTAMP input in microseconds like this:

> USING TIMESTAMP 1460634494030

Comment: yes I convert the date to long to got microsecond, but doesn't work ! I am asking in each time you generate this value when you do update or you take the old value from the DB !